# How does one conditionally get null as a default value in cookiecutter prompts?

Tags: jinja2, cookiecutter

Here is my example cookiecutter.json and Jinja logic

```json
{
    "pick_one": [
        "Choice A",
        "Choice B"
    ],
    "user_name": "{%- if cookiecutter.pick_one == 'Choice A' -%} mydefault {%- else -%}  null {%- endif -%}",
    "full_name": null
}
```

Notice that `full_name`'s default value is null, and this means an entry from the user is required.

For `user_name`, I'd like to have one default based on the `pick_one` value or null if not that value. In other words,  If Choice A is selected, I'd like the default to be `mydefault` and if not, I'd like null to be the default and `user_name` to work the same as `full_name` does in the example.

So far, I've tried wrapping null in curly braces, added safe to it.
`{{ null }}` or `{{ null | safe }}` but I get an error that the variable cannot be rendered because 'null' is undefined.
In other attempts, I get the string "null" as a default instead of requiring the user to enter a value.

Thanks so much!